# Extract URLs from .xml file

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, patch

I have task to write a PowerShell script which will make MBSA scan and will download and install all missing patches.

I am able to generate such report and save it as .xml file. Here is small part of this report:

[image]

I would like to extract all URLs between `<DownloadURL>` and `</DownloadURL>` but my code do not work:

```
Select-String -Path "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\results1.xml" -Pattern '(?<=DownloadURL>).*?(?=<\Q/\EDownloadURL)' -AllMatches |
    % { $_.Matches } |
    % { $_.Value } > "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\results1.txt"
```

I received following error:

> Select-String : parsing "(?<=DownloadURL>).*?(?=<\Q/\EDownloadURL)" - Unrecognized escape sequence \Q.

I tried `(?=<\\Q/\\EDownloadURL)` and `(?=<%5CQ/%5CEDownloadURL)` but after this results1.txt have nothing inside.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Remove `\Q` and `\E`, they are not supported in a .NET regex. `'(?<=DownloadURL>).*?(?=</DownloadURL)'`

Comment: Powershell can handle xml files, `[xml](Get-Content "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\results1.xml")` should get you a correct Powershell Object to use.

Comment: Please avoid adding images of code. Add a coed snippet instead. It helps possible answerees to give you a solution. I cannot test a possible script agains an image. Thx.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you very much! Works perfect
@Paxz I will try this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about power-shell commands but the regex should be like this:
`<DownloadURL>(.*)<\\DownloadURL>`